# Azure Function cosmosdb Environment settings

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-function-app

Hi I am writing Azure function trigger to capture changes for cosmosdb. I am facing a basic problem.

In function.json, I would like to keep the below parameters dynamic ( It should be picked from environment variable). The reason is that the same app will be deployed in multiple environments and they may have different database name.

```
      "databaseName": "CosmosDbName",
      "collectionName": "UserCollectionName",
```

I tried setting the values in local.settings.json to test it but it failed and didn't pick the values.

Any suggestions ?

Found the solution

```
      "databaseName": "%CosmosDbName%",
      "collectionName": "%UserCollectionName%",
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I have compiled your conclusion, can you mark it as the answer to end this question? This may help others. You can also post the answer yourself, if that, I will delete my answer. ;)

Comment: Thanks Bowman. I have accepted your answer. It explains it nicely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as you finally found, for the string type, you can use the method %% to set dynamic parameters, and then set the corresponding value in the environment variable(locally, it is set in local.settings.json. On Azure, it needs to set in the Configuration.), %% will match the corresponding value. It should be noted that the dynamic setting of %% is only applicable to string type, other types are not.

Set it like this in the function definition section:

```
  "databaseName": "%CosmosDbName%",
  "collectionName": "%UserCollectionName%",
```

Then fill in the corresponding key values in the settings.

Comment: Just to add, public documentation of how binding expressions work is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns